# Knockout: Extendable Themeable Components

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am revamping a knockout-based web-app, that will have different themes. The variations between themes can be in the view as well as functionality. Some functionality is specific to the theme, while other functionality can be common in 2 or more themes, but not all. Still other functionality can be all the themes.

The goal is to have have framework that provides maintainability by removing code duplication, having proper structure, loosely bounded functionality and improved testability.

I am envisioning components that contain reusable functionality. I am calling them **"base"** components. These components can be configured via configuration parameters. These components are not specific to any theme.

I would like to make a framework that allows:

- The base components to be included in themes.
- Themes can provide the theme-specific view of base component, that will over-ride the view provided by the base component.
- Themes can provide configuration parameters, specific to the theme.
- Themes can extend the functionality of base components. The extended component will have all the functionality of the base component
- Themes can have components specific to the theme.
- Component dependencies are managed by RequireJS
- The framework should support optimization through r.js
- Each component should be individually unit-testable
- Communication between components is based on pub-sub mechanism e.g. [ko.postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox)

In order to realize the above requirements, I am using [components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) support provided in Knockout 3.2+

I have been able to handle theme-specific views, but not able to find a way to extend the "base" component in the theme.

Any ideas about that is welcome.

---

I have create two KO components: "base-menu" and "menu".

"base-menu" component is:

```
define("base-menu", ['knockout'], function (ko) {

function ViewModel(params) {

    // this parameter should be configurable in theme
    var name = params.name || "No Name";

    this.name = ko.observable(name);

    this.dispose = function () {
        console.log("base dispose");
    }

};

return {
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    template: '<h2><span data-bind="text: name"></span> Settings in BASE</h2>'
};
});
```

"menu" component is:

```
// TODO: this component should "inherit" from base-menu, so that it has a "name" observable

define("menu", ['knockout'], function (ko) {

function ViewModel(params) {
    this.sections = params.sections || [];
    this.selectedSection = ko.observable();

    this.dispose = function () {
        // TODO: this should call base-menu's dispose function
        console.log("theme dispose");
    }

};

return {
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    template: '<h2><span data-bind="text: name"></span> Settings in THEME</h2><ul class="nav nav-pills" data-bind="foreach: sections"><li data-bind="css: { active: $parent.selectedSection() === $data }"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.selectedSection"></a></li></ul>'
};
});
```

"menu" component should "inherit" from "base-menu" component, so that it has a "name" observable.

How can I achieve this?

Editable example is given at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waqqasjabbar/5mfd69yb/)

Comment: You might want to add some sort of code to your question, as it runs a risk of being closed as "too broad" in its current form. Pick a representative example of the functionality you have problems implementing and create an abstract [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) out of that.

Comment: @Tomalak. Added example and code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using prototypal inheritance - although it's a bit ugly, especially without the `super` concept to call the base methods. You might consider using ES2015 and transpile that via Babel so you get a cleaner class syntax.

```
// TODO: this component should "inherit" from base-menu, so that it has a "name" observable

define("menu", ['knockout', 'base-menu'], function (ko, baseMenu) {

function ViewModel(params) {
    baseMenu.viewModel.call(this, params);
    this.sections = params.sections || [];
    this.selectedSection = ko.observable();

    this.dispose = function () {
        baseMenu.viewModel.prototype.dispose.call(this);
        // TODO: this should call base-menu's dispose function
        console.log("theme dispose");
    }

};
ViewModel.prototype = new baseMenu.viewModel();

return {
    viewModel: ViewModel,
    template: '<h2><span data-bind="text: name"></span> Settings in THEME</h2><ul class="nav nav-pills" data-bind="foreach: sections"><li data-bind="css: { active: $parent.selectedSection() === $data }"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.selectedSection"></a></li></ul>'
};
});
```

```
// menu.{js|ts|es6}
// Same thing in ES2015/ES6/TypeScript
import ko, { observable } from 'knockout;
import { viewModel as BaseMenu } from 'base-menu';

export class viewModel extends BaseMenu {
    constructor(params) {
        super(params);
        this.sections = params.sections || [];
        this.selectedSection = observable();
    }
    dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }
};

export var template = 'Your template here';
```

Comment: How about using mixins to extend the "menu" viewmodel from "base-menu"